# How do I know if Ubuntu installed completely?

Tags: unity, system-installation, animations

It seems that Ubuntu has been acting sluggish and some of the animations are off, amongst other annoyances. I've installed it a while ago and I've done all my fixes to the brightness and restart and other fixes and I also installed my software and I've got it to pretty much how I want it to be. I don't want to undo it all and reinstall the OS, so I wondering if there was way to make sure it installed correctly or if there's a way to fix Ubuntus problems through terminal, similar to "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

gives as output:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

you're fully updated and that's it...

If you have any further specific annoyances, click on [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and specify each annoyance in one single question giving as much detail as you can that pertains to that annoyance.
E.G. for a graphics related issue, state the OS version, kernel version, GPU, GPU memory, module versions of the GPU and for general sluggishness: the OS version, kernel version, `free --human`, `iostat`, `df --human`